# Passing a function as argument to other function

Tags: c, function, arguments

I have been reading about this theme. I have readed a lot of possible solutions, so please, dont mark my question as duplicated, only need a puntual solution of this problem.

I have a function which calculate time of execution of some code. This code will be sent as argument (will be a function).

This is the function which calculate the time:

```
double executionTime( /* HERE I WANNA PASS THE FUNCTION TO CALCULATE EXECTIME*/ )
{
    LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
    LARGE_INTEGER start;
    LARGE_INTEGER end;
    double interval;

    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);

    // HERE GOES CODE TO PROCCESS

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);
    interval = (double) (end.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) / frequency.QuadPart;

    return (interval);
}
```

I have tryed this (and another ways, but it is the most visible):

```
double executionTime( void (*f)() )
{
    LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
    LARGE_INTEGER start;
    LARGE_INTEGER end;
    double interval;

    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);

    // Function to proccess
    f();

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);
    interval = (double) (end.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) / frequency.QuadPart;

    return (interval);
}
```

I do not know if arguments of function to proccess are important. In some sites said yes, in another said no. The declaration of the function that I wanna proccess is:

```
int readFileAndInsertRegs(char *nombreFichero, PERSONA *tablaHash[], int tam, int tipoInsertado, int tipoPruebaColision)
```

I have called function `executionTime` like:

```
executionTime( readFileAndInsertRegs("./files/listaActores.csv", &tablaHash, TAM_E1, NORMAL, LINEAL) );
```

Can anyone help me with this particular problem?

Thank you.

Comment: What you're trying (passing a function and its arguments to be executed by some other code) isn't really possible in C. A better model would be to call a start/stop timer routine before and after the function you're trying to time. You could then embed all that in a macro if you want function-like semantics. Even better might be the statement expression extensions if your compiler supports that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usually the way to do so is to pass function arguments to the `executionTime` and call the function with them, i.e.

```
double executionTime( void (*f)(), char *arg1, PERSONE arg2[], ... )
{
    // do preamble

     f(arg1, arg2, .....);

    // finish
}

...

executionTime( &readFileAndInsertRegs, "./files/listaActores.csv", &tablaHash, TAM_E1, NORMAL, LINEAL));
```

here is a working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void process1(void (*f)(), int farg) {
  f(farg);
}

void f1(int arg) {
  printf("f1: %d\n", arg);
}

int main() {
  process1(&f1, 10);
  return 0;
}
```

and, in 'c' you do not need to declare all arguments of the function, though you can, and it is a good idea to do so. Compiler could do an additional checking then

```
    void process1(void (*f)(int), int farg) {
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is working, I am very grateful. Do you know if exist anyway of doing arguments dynamic? I mean, dont especify which arguments I will send, this way I could use ExecTime function with all other functions regardless its parameters (the idea is something like in main with *argc and *argv[])

Comment: not really. 1) If the functions you test are variadic (use varargs), you can make your `executionTime` variadic as well and pass varargs to the function. 2) Another idea is to pack all args in a struct and pass it as as `void *` around. Again the function should cast it to a correct struct internally. 3) You can make the `executionTime` variadic and use a `switch` statement to call a small variety of functions with different params.

Comment: Oh, ok, thank you. Can you update your answer with examples of each option? I would like saw it coded due to I do not understand so good what you mean. Or if you prefer I ask another question, and you answer it if you can... As you prefer :) I am so interested about this theme, and I will be so grateful :)

Comment: @JuMoGar this would be outside of the original question. You should ask another one.

Comment: Ok, I have done that. If you can answer it, I will be grateful. This is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52817011/how-to-make-a-function-which-receive-other-function-as-param-with-no-known-para