# How to make a function which receive other function as param (with no known parameters)

Tags: c, function, parameters

Previously I asked *How to make a function which receive a function as param* in C language. I get an answer [Link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52788832/7757135) but this solution is based on the parameters of argument's function. I mean:

```
int functionToPassAsParameter (int arg1, int arg2){
    // do something
}

int functionWhichReceiveFunction (int (*f)(), int arg1, int arg2){
    // do something
    f(arg1, arg2);
    // do something
}

// How to call the function
functionWhichReceiveFunction (&functionToPassAsParameter, 1, 2);
```

I would like something like:

```
int functionToPassAsParameter (int arg1, int arg2){
    // do something
}

int functionWhichReceiveFunction ( f() ){
    // do something
    f();
    // do something
}

// How to call the function
functionWhichReceiveFunction ( functionToPassAsParameter(arg1, arg2) );
```

So, when I call the function, I pass the correctly params but when I define the function which receive the other function I do not specify which params I will send to it. Is that possible to make?

---

**EDIT 1:** 
I wanna achieve pass any function to `functionWhichReceiveFunction`. Something like:

```
int function_a (int param1, int param2) { /* Do something */ };
void function_b (char *arg1) { /* Do something */ };

// Call the function with two differents functions regardless return type nor params
int x = functionWhichReceiveFunction ( function_a(param1, param2) );
functionWhichReceiveFunction ( function_b(arg1) );
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with your suggested approach, that is isn't already solved by the first approach?

Comment: The first approach is needed to define the params which will be sent. The second approach don't receive any param, so it's dinamyc, I can use it sending any functions. On the first approach only can send the same function always

Comment: How about function pointer?

Comment: How would you call the function in that case? It almost sounds like you're trying to recreate polymorphism.

Comment: How would you call a function if you don't know its signature? You can use opaque pointers as argument and call with opaque pointer as `void func(void*(*f)(void *), void *arg) { f(arg) }` but at some place the opaque pointer need to be handled and underling type need to be know so that you can make something useful with it. Where is the main question in software engineering.

Comment: take `pthread_create` as example

Comment: @geckos I have tryed your option, but this not work for me. If you can, ask my question with a functionable example. Maybe I do something bad.

Comment: What would the `functionWhichReceiveFunction` signature be, just think about it. You may be looking for instrospection: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection but I don't think this is the case. Anyway, show the problem that you're having, instead of asking for help with what you think that is the solution, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: I have updated question. Maybe now is more readable

Comment: If you want to chain function calls as `f(g(h(i(something))))` then you only have to worry with the return value of the functions, but in this case you're not passing functions as parameters, but result of functions, something completely different

Comment: If I'm not mistaking, such a function pointer is called a `functor`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the function to be passed to take a `void *` as a parameter.  That way the function that calls the given function doesn't need to know anything specific about the parameters:

```
struct params1 {
   int arg1;
   int arg2;
};

struct params2 {
   char *arg1;
   char *arg2;
};

int functionToPassAsParameter (void *param){
    struct params1 *args = params;
    // do something
}

int otherFunctionToPassAsParameter (void *param){
    struct params2 *args = params;
    // do something
}

int functionWhichReceiveFunction (int (*f)(void *), void *args) {
    // do something
    f(args);
    // do something
}

struct params1 p1 = { 1, 2 };
functionWhichReceiveFunction (&functionToPassAsParameter, &p1);
struct params2 p2 = { "abc", "def" };
functionWhichReceiveFunction (&otherFunctionToPassAsParameter, &p2);
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this solution. Instead of `structs` the params can not be passed one to one? I mean: `function(param1, param2)` instead of `function(struct_params)` ? Or something like `main(int argc, char *argv[])` ?

Comment: You don't add the `&` when passing the function; the compiler will pass oits address. `void *` will only work for pointes, not for other type of parameters.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to pass a function with unknown parameters to a function, declare the function that will pass the function as follows:

```
int g(int (*f)());
```

The function that is actually passed can have any number of parametes, for example:

```
int f(int x, void *y);
```

The call is now as follows:

```
g(f);
```

The above means that `g` passes `f`, which can have zero or more parameters of any type. This is denoted by the empty parameter list.

A particular function that may need to be passed is for example `f`.

Now `g` is called with function `f`, or any other function.

Note that it is up to `g` to know which parameters must be passed in calling `f`. So you need a "protocol" that tells `g` which function/type is passed. For example, besides passing the function, pass an identifier (int) that says what type of function is passed, for example:

```
#define fS_I_I  1   // f needs String, int, Int
#define fD_I    2   // f needs Double, Int
#define fI_I    3   // f needs Int, Int

int g(int ID, int (*f)());

g(fI_I, f);
```

Comment: int f(int x, void *y) {
    return x;
};


int g(int (*f)()) {
    int x = f();
    printf("X is: %d", x);
};

int main()
{
    g( f(1, 2) );
    return 0;
}

Comment: I will answer my question with a code bassed on your example. Could you say me where I am wrong? My code is not working

Answer (score 1):

Learn more about [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))s and [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union)s. Notice that C don't have them. You might want to emulate that with [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming))s

> I wanna achieve pass any function to `functionWhichReceiveFunction`

**You cannot do that** simply and portably. Remember that the signature of a function in C is related to its [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) (so to the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) used by your compiler and your code; for examples, look into [Linux x86 ABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI)s; so floating point arguments could be passed in *different registers* as integral arguments, so your compiler needs to know the signature of all your function pointers). You need to also give to `functionWhichReceiveFunction` something which describes the signature.

What you might consider doing, assuming your platform have function pointers of the same size and in the same address space as data pointers (this is very often the case), is to pass to `functionWhichReceiveFunction` a `void*` pointer (actually, a function pointer casted to `void*`) and an enumeration describing it.

For example

```
enum funsig_en {
  funsig_void_to_void,
  funsig_int_to_void,
  funsig_int_to_double,
  funsig_int_double_to_void,
};
```

Then, you'll have corresponding function signatures (types)

```
typedef void fun_void_to_void(void);
typedef void fun_int_to_void(int);
typedef double fun_int_to_double(int);
typedef void fun_int_double_to_void(int, double);
```

Suppose you have these static functions

```
static void statf_void_to_void(void);
static void statf_int_to_void(int);
static double statf_int_to_double(int);
static void statf_int_double_to_void(int, double);
```

You might declare

```
void 
functionWhichReceiveFunction (void*res, enum funsig_en sigkind, void*fun, ...);
```

and you could use it as

```
functionWhichRecieveFunction(NULL, funsig_void_to_void
                             (void*)statf_void_to_void);
```

or

```
functionWhichRecieveFunction(NULL, funsig_int_to_void, 
                             (void*)statf_int_to_void, 123);
```

or

```
double r = 0;
functionWhichRecieveFunction(&r, funsig_int_to_double, 
                             (void*)statf_int_to_double, 2345);
```

---

I leave you to code that variadic `functionWhichRecieveFunction`. You need [stdarg(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdarg.3.html) facilities. It would include code like

```
va_args arglist;
va_start (arglist, fun);
switch(sigkind) {
case funsig_int_to_void: {
  int a = va_arg(arglis, int);
  fun_int_to_void* fptr = (fun_int_to_void*)fun;
  (*fptr)(a);
  return;
} // end case funsig_int_to_void
```

much later you'll need some `va_end(arglis);` near the end of your `functionWhichRecieveFunction` body.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is using varargs. In the following example every function being called does its own interpretation of parameters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

// expects 4 arguments (int, int, int, char*)
void f1(va_list args) {
    int a, b, c;
    char *d;

    a = va_arg(args, int);
    b = va_arg(args, int);
    c = va_arg(args, int);
    d = va_arg(args, char *);

    printf("%d, %d, %d: %s\n", a, b, c, d);
}

// expects 3 ars (int, int, char*);
void f2(va_list args) {
    int a, b;
    char *c; 

    a = va_arg(args, int);
    b = va_arg(args, int);
    c = va_arg(args, char *);

    printf("%d, %d: %s\n", a, b, c);
}



void caller(void (*f)(va_list), ...) {
    va_list args;

    va_start(args, f);
    f(args);
    va_end(args);
}


int main() {
    caller(&f1, 0, 1, 3, "hello");
    caller(&f2, 1, 2, "bye");
    return 0;
}
```

Another possibility is to have `caller` to interpret parameters based on some type info and call a correct function call. This might be useful if you have a limited number of argument patterns and just regular functions to call:

```
void f3(int a, int b, int c, char *d) {
    printf("%d, %d, %d: %s\n", a, b, c, d);
}

void f4(int a, int b, char *c) {
    printf("%d, %d: %s\n", a, b, c);
}

typedef enum  {
    type1, type2
} Types;

void caller1(Types t, void (*f)(), ...) {
    va_list args;

    va_start(args, f);
    switch (t) {
    case type1: {
        int a, b, c;
        char *d;

        a = va_arg(args, int);
        b = va_arg(args, int);
        c = va_arg(args, int);
        d = va_arg(args, char *);

        f(a,b,c,d);
        break;
    }
    case type2: {
        int a, b;
        char *c;

        a = va_arg(args, int);
        b = va_arg(args, int);
        c = va_arg(args, char *);

        f(a,b,c);
    }
    }
    va_end(args);

}

int main() {

    caller1(type1, &f3, 3,2,1, "hi");
    caller1(type2, &f4, 3,2,"take care");

    return 0;
```

Comment: From C++ documentation: "A function that invokes va_start, shall also invoke va_end before it returns". _va_end(args)_ needs to added at the end of the _caller_ function.

Answer (score 0):

@Paul Ogilvie, this is the code:

```
int f(int x, void *y) {
    return x;
};


int g(int (*f)()) {
    int x = f(1, NULL);     // call f with parameters
    printf("X is: %d", x);
    return(x);              // return result
};

int main()
{
    //g( f(1, 2) );   // this passes the result of a call to f, not f
    g( f );           // this passes f
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the call of `f` in `g` you must pass parameters.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This works. But there is no way of pass parameters inside main call? I mean: `g( f(1, 2) );` (the line that you commented). That is exacly what i am searching. Hope it could be possible

Comment: No, you can't tell `g` which prms to pass to `f` the way you did, as that notation means a _call_ of `f`. You can add prms to `g` of course, e.g. `g(f,1,2);` (and adapt `g` to take more prms)

Comment: You could use varargs for `g`: `int g(int (*f)(), ...)`